# Show every Mobius transformation $T(z)=\frac{\alpha z+ \beta}{\bar \beta z+ \bar \alpha}$ acts as an isometry of the hyperbolic disk

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Consider the unit disk $\mathbb{D}=\{z: |Z| < 1\} \subset \mathbb{C}$ equipped with the hyperbolic metric $g$ induced by $1$ form $ds=\frac{|dz|}{(1-|z|^2)}$

I am trying to show that every Mobius transformation 
$T(z)=\frac{\alpha z+ \beta}{\bar \beta z+ \bar \alpha}$

with $|\alpha|^2 -|\beta|^2=1$ acts as an isometry of the hyperbolic disk.

This is the proof:

The main idea is to show the pull back of the metric in the $w$ plane is identical in the $z$ plane.

$$dw=\frac{\alpha(\bar \beta z- \bar \alpha )-\bar \beta(\alpha z + \beta)}{(\bar \beta z+ \bar \alpha)^2} dz = \frac{|\alpha|^2 - |\beta|^2}{(\bar \beta z+ \bar \alpha)} dz=\frac{dz}{(\bar \beta z+ \bar \alpha)^2}$$

We can see that $$|w|^2=\frac{\alpha z+ \beta}{\bar \beta z + \bar \alpha} \times \frac{\overline{\alpha z + \beta}}{\bar \beta z + \bar \alpha}$$

> How do we get from this step to $1-|w|^2=\frac{(|\alpha|^2 -|\beta
>  |^2)(1-|z|^2)}{(\bar \beta z + \bar \alpha )^2}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\alpha z+\beta}{\overline\beta z+\overline\alpha}\cdot\frac{\overline\alpha\overline z+\overline\beta}{\beta \overline z+\alpha}=\frac{|\alpha|^2|z|^2+\alpha\overline\beta z+\overline\alpha\beta\overline z+|\beta|^2}{|\beta\overline z +\alpha|^2}=\frac{|\alpha|^2|z|^2+\alpha\overline\beta z+\overline\alpha\beta\overline z+|\beta|^2}{|\beta\overline z +\alpha|^2}$$

Also, observe that

$$|\beta\overline z+\alpha|^2=|\beta|^2|z|^2+2\text{ Re}\,(\overline\alpha\beta\overline z)+|\alpha|^2\implies(\beta\overline z+\alpha)^2-|\alpha|^2|z|^2-\alpha\overline\beta z-\overline\alpha\beta\overline z-|\beta|^2=$$

$$=(|\beta|^2-|\alpha|^2)|z|^2+|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2=1-|z|^2$$

and you have your equality

Comment: so then you get $\frac{|\alpha|^2 |z|^2 + \alpha \bar \beta z + \bar \alpha \beta z + |\beta|^2}{1-|z|^2}$? That is different to what I am trying to get to

Comment: @Aljabra Nop, I get $$1-|w|^2=\frac{1-|z|^2}{|\overline\alpha+\overline\beta z}|^2$$ which is *almost* what you got (remember: $|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2=1\;$...!), but in the expression of $\;|w|^2\;$ you had to multiply by the conjugate of the denominator and, apparently, you messed up here.

Comment: How can we see that $|w|^2=\frac{\alpha z+ \beta}{\bar \beta z + \bar \alpha} \times \frac{\overline{\alpha z + \beta}}{\bar \beta z + \bar \alpha}$?

Comment: @Aljabra Thats true for any complex number $\;z:\;\;|z|^2=z\overline z\;$ , but in your case the conjugate overline is over *the whole fraction* !

Comment: Lastly how does $(|\beta|^2 - |\alpha|^2) |z|^2 + |\alpha|^2 - |\beta|^2=1-|z|^2$?

Comment: @Aljabra Read two comments above! And also read *carefully* the given information in your question.

Comment: In your original answer you showed $|\beta \bar z + \alpha|^2$ rather than for $|\beta \bar z + \bar \alpha|^2$, Does it make a difference?