# Show $\int_ {\mathbb{D}}f(\frac{\alpha(x_1+ix_2)+\beta}{\bar{\beta}(x_1+ix_2)+\bar{\alpha}})d\mu(x_1,x_2)=\int_ {\mathbb{D}}f(x_1+ix_2)d\mu(x_1,x_2)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

*Definitions needed in the problem:*

$\text{SU}(1,1)=\left\{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha & \beta \\\overline\beta & \overline\alpha \end{array} \right)\mid \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb C,|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2=1\right\}$

$\mathbb{D}={\{(x_1+ix_2)\in\mathbb{C}:(x_1^2+x_2^2)<1}\}$

*Problem:*

Let $d\mu(x_1, x_2) =\frac{4}{(1- (x_1 ^ 2 + x_2 ^ 2)) ^ 2}d\lambda(x_1, x_2)$ where $\lambda$ denotes the measure of Lebesgue on the unit disk $\mathbb{D} $. Show that for all $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha & \beta \\\overline\beta & \overline\alpha \end{array} \right)\in\text{SU}(1,1)$, $f\in\text{L}_1(\mathbb{D},\mu)$:

$\int_ {\mathbb{D}}f(\frac{\alpha(x_1+ix_2)+\beta}{\bar{\beta}(x_1+ix_2)+\bar{\alpha}})d\mu(x_1,x_2)=\int_ {\mathbb{D}}f(x_1+ix_2)d\mu(x_1,x_2)$

*Idea (proof):* Let $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha & \beta \\\overline\beta & \overline\alpha \end{array} \right)\in\text{SU}(1,1)$, $f\in\text{L}_1(\mathbb{D},\mu)$ then $|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2=1$ and

---

> $\int_ {\mathbb{D}}f(\frac{\alpha(x_1+ix_2)+\beta}{\bar{\beta}(x_1+ix_2)+\bar{\alpha}})d\mu(x_1,x_2)=\int_ {\mathbb{D}}f(\frac{\beta\bar{\beta}-\alpha\bar{\alpha}}{\bar{\beta}^2}((x_1+ix_2)+\frac{\bar{\alpha}}{\bar{\beta}})^{-1}+\frac{\alpha}{\bar{\beta}})d\mu(x_1,x_2)=\int_ {\mathbb{D}}f(\frac{-1}{\bar{\beta}^2}((x_1+ix_2)+\frac{\bar{\alpha}}{\bar{\beta}})^{-1}+\frac{\alpha}{\bar{\beta}})d\mu(x_1,x_2)$

---

How can I continue?
Can anybody help me please?

Thanks...

Comment: It might be useful to mention where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints for you.

You can show that $\varphi:z\to\frac{z\alpha+\beta}{z\bar{\beta}+\bar{\alpha}}$ is an isometry based on the hyperbolic metric, and you can also prove that it is a **bijective** function of $\mathbb{D}$ onto $\mathbb{D}$. Therefore, $d\mu(z)=d\mu(\varphi(z))$ and thus
$$\int_{\mathbb{D}}f(\varphi(z))d\mu(\varphi(z))=\int_{\mathbb{D}}f(z)d\mu(z)$$
since $\varphi(\mathbb{D})=\mathbb{D}$. Because $|\varphi(\infty)|>1$ and $|\varphi^{-1}(\infty)|>1$, this Mobius transformation is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$.

If you need more details of the proof, please check the link below or make a comment.

[Prove that $\varphi$ is an isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763111/show-every-mobius-transformation-tz-frac-alpha-z-beta-bar-beta-z-bar?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you very much friend, I already proved that $ \varphi $ is a bijective function and an isometry with respect to hyperbolic metrics. I still have two questions, we know that $d\mu(z)=d\mu(\varphi(z))$ for being $\varphi$ an isometry. (First) Why is equality fulfilled $\int_{\mathbb{D}\cup\infty}f(\varphi(z))d\mu(\varphi(z))=\int_{\mathbb{D}\cup\infty}f(z)d\mu(z)$?

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very clear to me. (Second) Can you explain how you got that $\lim_{z\to\infty} |f(\varphi(z)d\mu(\varphi(z))|<\infty$?

Comment: @J.rafa $\varphi(\infty)=\frac{\alpha}{\bar{\beta}}$ and then plug it in you will find $|f(\varphi(\infty))d\mu(\varphi(\infty))|<\infty$

Comment: Perfect thank you friend.

Comment: What book advises me to study these things?

Comment: @J.rafa I am not sure whether this is a good question to be in the comment, but Geometry and Spectra of Compact Riemann Surfaces by Peter Buser is a great book for you to learn about compact Riemann surfaces.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have another question, what is the preimage of $ \infty $, that is, who is $ z_1\in\mathbb{D} $ such that $ \varphi (z_1) = \infty $?

Comment: Did you comment that $ \varphi (\infty) = \frac{\alpha}{\bar{\beta}} $, $\frac{\alpha}{\bar{\beta}} \in \mathbb{D} $?

Comment: @J.rafa $\varphi^{-1}(\infty)=-\frac{\bar{\alpha}}{\bar{\beta}}$.

Comment: @J.rafa Sorry that was my mistake. Actually you don't need to think about the point at infinity since $|\varphi(\infty)|=\frac{|\alpha|}{|\beta|}>1$ and $|\varphi^{-1}(\infty)|>1$, which suggests these two points are not in $\mathbb{D}$. I will revise my answer. The bijective and isometry parts still work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99900/discussion-between-yourong-zang-and-j-rafa).